# Interesting behaviour with preventDefault and .remove() - can I rely on this?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I set up an AJAX form (actually I am making yet another edit-in-place plugin) and set up an AJAX binding for the click button:

```
    // Do default submit and cancel options.
    $editor.on('click' + namespace, '.ok', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked ok');
        submit($original);
    });
```

(Here $editor is the form, and $original is the span element being edited-in-place; after submitting, I need to show the span element again. The form contains a `<button>` of type `submit` and class `.ok`.)

To my surprise, the default form action actually *was* suppressed, even though I'd neglected to `.preventDefault()` or anything else. I eventually traced this to the fact that the AJAX submission routine will eventually do:

```
$editor.remove();
```

i.e. annihilate the entire form. It seems to work even if I merely .detach() it, though.

Can this behaviour be relied upon? Should it be relied upon? Does the sudden disappearance of the form prevent the browser from submitting it in the normal way, or could it have cached the information prior to dispatching events? (Are there any web standards that say anything about this?) Could it cause exceptions (or even a crash?) with some browsers to sweep a form away from under its feet? If so, what other implications does this have for proper design besides just using .preventDefault?

---

Addendum: It seems that pressing the Enter key, which normally submits a form, will actually generate a `click` event for the OK button as well! Is that supposed to happen? Again, removing the form in the Enter-key handler seems to prevent the click from happening.

The thing is that, because I am making a plugin, I intend to allow for the possibility that the OK button doesn't actually get attached to the form; in this case the Enter key still needs to work, but I obviously only want to submit the form once if the button is there...

Comment: I am not seeing that behavior in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uuwkt/  Are you doing something different than what I mocked up?

Comment: Maybe it is indeed browser-specific, then. With your fiddle, I get a 404 page when I comment out the remove call, and nothing (except the `console.log` message) otherwise. I expect it makes more sense to leave it in anyway, but then I still need to know what to do about the Enter key. It would be nice not to have to detect whether the button was actually added...